# Will re-doing a MvM mission on Mann Up mode use up another ticket?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

Will re-doing a MvM mission on Mann Up mode use up another ticket?

For example, I'm on my second tour of the *Mecha Engine* Tour, and I've completed the first 2 missions for the tour, using up 2 Tour of Duty tickets. If I play the first mission again through Mann Up mode, will I use up *another* TOD ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not be used, as stated in the FAQ for TF2 MvM.

> Q: What if I complete a Mission that I have already completed on my Tour of Duty Badge?
>
> In this case, your Tour of Duty Ticket will not be consumed, and your Tour of Duty progress will not be updated. Squad Surplus Vouchers, however, will always be redeemed for items when a Mission is completed successfully.

[Source](http://www.teamfortress.com/mvm/faq/)